# File Share Doesn't Allow Any Higher Permission Than Authenticated Users On Specific Machines

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, network-share

**THE SETUP**

I have a Server with a file share on my Windows Server 2008 R2 server:

\SERVER1\SHARE1

I have made myself a domain group called "Share Access".

In the NTFS Permissions of the folder I remove everyone but "Share Access" with Full Control. In the Share Permissions I give "Share Access" full control.

**THE PROBLEM**

I log into another Windows Server 2008 R2 Server and go to the share but it says I don't have permissions to access the folder.

THE TROUBLESHOOTING

I have added "Everyone" to the NTFS and Share and go back to the second server and go to the share and it lets me in.
I remove "Everyone" and add "Authenticated Users" to the NTFS and share and go back to the second server and go to the share and it lets me in.
I remove "Authenticated users" and add "Domain Users" to the NTFS and share and go back to the second server and go to the share and it DOES NOT LET ME IN.
I have logged onto about a dozen Windows 7 computers on the same domain and I can still get into the share.
I have logged into other Windows Server 2008 R2 servers in the same domain and I can still get into the share.

Can anyone tell me why its just this specific server that doesn't see me as anything other than an authenticated user as it comes to this share or why I can't get into the share?

Comment: Does "Share Access" appear in the output of the `whoami /groups` command?  If not, have you tried logging out and back in to the troublesome server?

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes "Share Access" does show up as a group in my whoami

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I was overzealous with maintaining the security of the share.

The NTFS settings were correct but the Share settings I overly modified.

The Share settings should have had:

Domain Users (Change, Read)
Administrators (Full Control)

I can now get back in to my share while keeping those out I need to keep out as the NTFS permission run the main privileges.